# how to optimize code to update the .c file

Tags: batch-file

```
@Echo on
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Set _PathtoFile=D:\VersionR.c
Set _OldLine=const version[6] = {"V3.13"}; 
Set _NewLine=const char version[6] = {"V3.14"};
Call :_Parse "%_PathtoFile%"

Set _Len=0
Set _Str=%_OldLine%
Set _Str=%_Str:"=.%987654321

:_Loop
If NOT "%_Str:~18%"=="" Set _Str=%_Str:~9%& Set /A _Len+=9& Goto _Loop
Set _Num=%_Str:~9,1%
Set /A _Len=_Len+_Num
PushD %_FilePath%
If Exist %_FileName%.new Del %_FileName%.new
If Exist %_FileName%.old Del %_FileName%.old
Set _LineNo=0
For /F "Tokens=* Eol=" %%I In (%_FileName%%_FileExt%) Do (
    Set _tmp=%%I
    Set /A _LineNo+=1
    If /I "!_tmp:~0,%_Len%!"=="%_OldLine%" (
        >>%_FileName%.new Echo %_NewLine%
    ) Else (
        If !_LineNo! GTR 1 If "!_tmp:~0,1!"=="[" Echo.>>%_FileName%.new
        SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
        >>%_FileName%.new Echo %%I
        EndLocal
    ))
Ren %_FileName%%_FileExt% %_FileName%.old
Ren %_FileName%.new %_FileName%.c
::call :_check


if /i exist "%~1\" (set "Folder=%~1") else (exit)
PopD
Goto :EOF
```

1. If file size is too long the code takes long time to execute. how to reduce it?
2. If update multiple variable from above code in a file.

Comment: Your code is incomplete, it includes a `call` to a label, which does not exist in your submission, `:_Parse `. It would also help, instead of expecting everyone to determine all of the steps of the task, by reading your, (requiring improvement), code, to actually explain the tasks along side that code.

Answer (score 1):

It looks that you only try to replace a build/version number in a c-file. It's much easier to add a `version.h` file with only just this information.

Something like

```
@echo off
Set version=V3.14

Set "CodeLine=const char version[] = {"%version%"};"

(
  echo #ifndef VERSION_H_
  echo #define VERSION_H_
  echo %codeLine%
  echo #endif
) > version.h
```

Comment: which placing version no in c file this code removed all other code of .c file.

Comment: @Ritvik That is the idea, to create a new small file. Just `#include "version.h"` from your c file. Btw. in a repo system, you don't want to modify a source file each time the version changes